# Saving value in Shared Preference giving error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-broadcastreceiver

[image: Here is my Logcat]I want to store a string value that is inside an if block and i want to access the value outside of it. Now i tried with this code but it is giving me error and app force closed by saying "Print ln needs a message". It is a broadcast receiver class and this code is in OnReceive method.
I tried with this code:

```
if (!available)
for (String key : contactNumber.keySet()) {
   String msgSender = contactNumber.get(key);
   extractedContact = Utilities.extractNumbers(key);
   preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("progress",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
   editor.putString("number", extractedContact);
   editor.apply();
   }

String showNumber = preferences.getString("number", "");
Toast.makeText(context, showNumber + "Hello",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Now I just want to store that extracted contact value in shared pref and then I am retrieving it outside an if Blocks but it is giving me error. Can anyone know whats the issue? How can i retrieve the stored value

Comment: ok lemme edit the post

Comment: @SathishKumarJ post edited please check

Comment: The important part of your Logcat is at the very bottom, could we see a bit more of the stack trace? Your problem exists on line 256 of your TodoRe class. Have you posted that line above? You're calling Log.i in an invalid way

Comment: @biddulph.r problem solved sir thankyou for your time

Comment: @MikeM. Ok next time i would be careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add below line before getting value from preferences.

as below,

```
      preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("progress",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     String showNumber = preferences.getString("number", "");
     Toast.makeText(context, showNumber + "Hello",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It means Preference not initialized, there is need intialize out of

```
for (String key : contactNumber.keySet()) {
..
}
```

So,

```
       if (!available)
    {
   preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("progress",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        for (String key : contactNumber.keySet()) {
           String msgSender = contactNumber.get(key);
           extractedContact = Utilities.extractNumbers(key);

           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
           editor.putString("number", extractedContact);
           editor.apply();
           }

        String showNumber = preferences.getString("number", "");
        Toast.makeText(context, showNumber + "Hello",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ...
    }// if (!available) close bracket
```

thanks..

Answer (score -3):

Replace this line of code

> editor.apply();

by

> editor.commit();

Comment: Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.